# In MYSQL, how do I get the most common string in a column after filtering out duplicate users with SELECT INSTINCT?

Tags: mysql

Started learning MYSQL last week and I have a question.  I'm trying to get the most popular color by amount of unique users from color_table (which would be Blue)

```
+---------+---------------+
| user    | color         |
+---------+---------------+
| John    | Brown         |
| Jack    | Red           |
| Stacy   | Blue          |
| Bob     | Green         |
| Jack    | Red           |
| Doe     | Blue          |
| Moe     | Orange        |
| Jack    | Red           |
| Jane    | Blue          |
| Nate    | Purple        |
| Jack    | Red           |             
+---------+---------------+
```

The color Red has duplicates of the same user so I strip them out with the following:

```
SELECT INSTINCT user, color FROM color_table; 

+---------+---------------+
| user    | color         |
+---------+---------------+
| John    | Brown         |
| Jack    | Red           |
| Stacy   | Blue          |
| Bob     | Green         |
| Doe     | Blue          |
| Moe     | Orange        |
| Jane    | Blue          |
| Nate    | Purple        |
+---------+---------------+
```

The table looks good afterwards but what do I do after this? Using SELECT INSTINCT on two columns, I can't get `Count(*)` and `ORDERBY DESC` and `LIMIT 1`  to work.  I think I need to put them in a subquery but I'm not sure.  I keep reading there are limitations to what SELECT INSTINCT can do so I'm not sure if that is the correct method to filter out the duplicates either for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is `INSTINCT`??

Comment: Your first issue is `INSTINCT` is not a key word of MySQL, you probably meant `DISTINCT`

Comment: Is there a reason that duplicates are allowed? (This isn't a judgement, just wondering if there is a reason :) ) Would it break anything with your app if duplicates were not allowed?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Could you really execute , SELECT INSTINCT user, color FROM color_table; What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key is to use distinct inside the count function.

SELECT color, count(distinct user) FROM color_table group by color;

Comment: This works.  Sorry about the misspelling guys.  I'm embarrassed.